# Как присвоить selected select option по значению из массива PHP?

Tags: php, html, массивы

Всем привет! Есть массив:

```
    Array (
[0] => Array ( [id] => 14 [c_name] => toto [url] => https://ranking.com [repetition] => 3 [ton] => 3 [type] => 2 [date] => 12.04.2018 ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 15 [c_name] => toto [url] => https://ranking.com [repetition] => 1 [ton] => 2 [type] => 4 [date] => 12.04.2018 ) 
[2] => Array ( [id] => 16 [c_name] => toto [url] => https://ranking.com [repetition] => 2 [ton] => 2 [ton] [type] =>4 [date] => 12.04.2018 ) )
```

Есть также таблица с селектами типа

```
echo "<td class='sel1'><select name=$arr[$i]['url'] class='custom-select ton' >
    <option  value='0' selected>Не определена</option>
    <option value='1'>Положительная</option>
    <option value='2'>Отрицательная</option>
    <option value='3'>Нейтральная</option>
    <option value='4'>Нерелевантная</option>
  </select></td>";
```

В этом массиве есть [ton], значение которого должно быть значением option. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так чтоб селекту с этим значением был присвоен selected.
цикл и вывод таблицы мне не нужен. необходимо лишь разобраться с селектом

Comment: А в чем проблема если вы заполняете option через цикл воткнуть туда и selected=""?

Comment: там уже определены значения. Суть в том что сделать выбранным именно тот option, значение которого равно значению [ton] массива. Но потом пользователь сможет перевыбирать option. надеюсь вы меня поняли

Answer (score 1):

1-й вариант - если вы уж прям вручную и никак по другому:

```
echo "<td class='sel1'><select name=$arr[$i]['url'] class='custom-select ton' >
  <option  value='0' <?if(empty($arr[$i]['ton'])){echo "selected";}?>>Не определена</option>
  <option value='1' <?if($arr[$i]['ton'] == 1){echo "selected";}?>>Положительная</option>
  <option value='2' <?if($arr[$i]['ton'] == 2){echo "selected";}?>>Отрицательная</option>
  <option value='3' <?if($arr[$i]['ton'] == 3){echo "selected";}?>>Нейтральная</option>
  <option value='4' <?if($arr[$i]['ton'] == 4){echo "selected";}?>>Нерелевантная</option>
</select></td>";
```

а лучше все же определить массивчик:

```
$arr_z = array('Не определена', 'Положительная','Отрицательная','Нейтральная', 'Нерелевантная');
echo "<td class='sel1'><select name=$arr[$i]['url'] class='custom-select ton' >
   <?foreach($arr_z as $key => $val){?>
        <option  value='<?=$key?>' <?if($arr[$i]['ton'] == $key){echo "selected";}?>><?=$val?></option>
   <?}?>
</select></td>";
```